# Tailwind: How to overflow-auto images when displaying them horizontally from a localStorage

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am facing a small problem that is related to the css stuff, the problem is that when I am mapping images to display them inside a div that has a max width, and when the images exceeds it they should be hidden and a scroll bar is used, and of course I have achieved this using the overflow-auto property, but that is not what is happening, for some reason the images are compressed by decreasing the width of each other to display the images that are added, and I am using tailwind framework, so what I want first is to make sure there is no problem in my tailwind code, because I do not think there is. Now my assumption that make me think that this problem is not a tailwind problem is that when I lost the images data, like you know the alt attribute will work, in this case the problem is not happening, there is a normal scroll bar that appears when there is an images that need more space to be seen, which what I want when the images data are there. So I think the problem is related to something with the images url that I am getting from local storage that have some effect that leads for this problem, but I do not have any idea what is the relation between them, and sorry for the long text.

This is the code:

```
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const HandleStory = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = localStorage.getItem("imageList")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("imageList"))
      : null;
    if (storedData) {
      setData(storedData);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleImageError = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {data.length > 0 && (
        <div className="bg-white rounded-md px-3 pb-3 max-w-[40rem] overflow-auto">
          <h2 className="font-semibold">Stories</h2>
          <div className="flex gap-3">
            {data.map((imageData, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="h-52 w-36 rounded-lg cursor-pointer shadow-lg hover:brightness-90 relative"
              >
                <div className="bg-gray-400 h-full flex rounded-lg">
                  <img
                    src={imageData.url}
                    onError={handleImageError}
                    alt="Story"
                    width="200"
                    height="200"
                    className="rounded-lg"
                  />
                  <span className="text-white absolute top-44 left-2">
                    {imageData.name}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HandleStory;
```